# K&R C Counting Characters

Tags: c, linux

I'm working out of the K&R book, and I'm on the code example of how to count characters from a stream of text. I copied their code and tried running it, but when the command line prompts you for characters, the loop doesn't exit and thus will never print out the character count. Is there an error here I'm not catching?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
     long nc;
     nc = 0;
     while(getchar() != EOF) {
          ++nc;
     }
     printf("%1d\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `EOF` with `'\n'`.

Comment: Did you try entering an `EOF` character?

Comment: I see my error - control + c on linux isn't an EOF character. Thanks! I'll accept an answer as soon as stack overflow lets me

Comment: or reboot `ctrl` `alt` `canc` :-)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I remember having the exact same confusion on this one. Think of it as an adjunct lesson.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you want to stop it just send the EOF signal to the shell.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in Linux or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> on Windows.

By the way (as additional info) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> send `SIGINT` to a process in Linux and on Windows it does something similar.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Fixed, indeed that could be misleading.

Comment: @PauloBu adding two links [Control-Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z) and [Control-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C)

Comment: Why would an uppercase "D" be misleading?  It's represented on-screen as `^D` and I've certainly never found it confusing.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what is SIGINT? Does it basically tell the machine to exit the code? (that's what it appeared to be on the surface)

Comment: Because one can think of it as `Ctrl+Shitf+D` probably.

Comment: @Andrew it sends the singal SIGINT (interrupt) to the process. Which its default behavior is to stop running the process.

Comment: @Paulo I would expect that to actually be written Ctrl+Shift+D, particularly when keycaps markup is present, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on Linux) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on Windows)? If yes then It will come out of loop for sure. On pressing these keys, it will return EOF and loop will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Try ending your character stream with CNTL-Z (end of file character). Just hitting `Enter` results in a `CR` which is just another character to count

Comment: *Just hitting Enter results in a CR which is just another character to count* I don't know?